# Is it better in a Makefile to expand variables early or late, specifically in recipe (and in conjunction with the eval function)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use in my Makefile a variable with eval which creates a static pattern-rule in each subdirs of my project. But there is two ways I can handle it.

```
define  STATIC_OBJ_RULE
$(OBJ_$(DIR)): $(OBJ_LOCAL_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_LOCAL_DIR)%.c $(DEP_LOCAL_DIR)%.dep \
| $(OBJ_LOCAL_DIR) $(DEP_LOCAL_DIR)
    $(COMPILE)
    $(POSTCOMPILE)
    $(RM) $$(word 2,$$^).tmp
    $(TOUCH) $$@
endef
```

or that way

```
define  STATIC_OBJ_RULE
$(OBJ_$(DIR)): $(OBJ_LOCAL_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_LOCAL_DIR)%.c $(DEP_LOCAL_DIR)%.dep \
| $(OBJ_LOCAL_DIR) $(DEP_LOCAL_DIR)
    $$(COMPILE)
    $$(POSTCOMPILE)
    $(RM) $$(word 2,$$^).tmp
    $(TOUCH) $$@
endef
```

(The difference being on the third line, escaping or not COMPILE and POSTCOMPILE, which generate the object file and the corresponding dependency file and do some post process on the dependency)

For the first case, that makes less expansion to do each time a recipe for an object file is run, but I need to escape other variables (which compose COMPILE and POSTCOMPILE) with a `$` (automatic variables among them)

On the other hand, since make purpose is to *avoid* recompilation (when unnecessary of course), does that really achieve anything ?

So would you consider one to be a best practice than the other ?
(or am I just overthinking over something that does not worth it ?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to do it the second way: the first way won't work.

Why is that?  Because if you have a variable `COMPILE` which expands to a compile line, the value of that variable *must* contain automatic variables like `$@`, `$<`, etc. or it can't work.  So for example it might be something like this:

```
COMPILE = $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

or something.

If you use your first method then the `COMPILE` variable will be expanded when the recipe is parsed, which means the automatic variables are expanded then not when the rule is being run, which means that they'll be empty and your recipe won't work.

In general I prefer to escape the contents of recipes when using define/eval like this, just so everything works the same way with tose recipes as it would work if you wrote them directly not using define/eval.